# Condition for fetching products having images first ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, product-collection

This is my function which is returning all products list on my homepage. I want to define a condition to fetch only products with images comes first then products with no images comes last.

I am using Magento 2.2.0

```
 protected function _getAllProductProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
            ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam(self::PAGE_VAR_NAME, 1));

        $conditions = $this->getConditions();
        $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
        $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

        return $collection;
    }
```